# Using requireJS with jquery-dependant library (responsiveIframe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, requirejs

I am having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around requireJS dependancy management. I've read the docs and all online resources plenty of times but I can't seem to get it working correctly.

End scenario: I have an embeddable widget that eventually will attach a responsive iFrame to a page. The outer page is assumed to have some version of jQuery, but to be safe I am including my own jQuery.

I am using a library called [responsiveIframe](http://npr.github.io/responsiveiframe/), which depends on jQuery.

Basically, when I call `$('#responsive-frame').responsiveIframe({xdomain: '*'});` from inside the `require` function, I get an undefined function error. When I change `$` to `jQuery` it works because it is able to use the existing library on the page (not what I want).

Here is the code (assume paths all work):

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4000/assets',
  paths: {
    'jquery': 'jquery-1.11.1.min',
    'responsiveIframe': 'jquery.responsiveiframe'
  },
  map: {
    '*': {'jquery': 'jquery-lc'},
    'jquery-lc': {'jquery': 'jquery'}
  }
});

require(['jquery', 'responsiveIframe'], function($) {
  $('#responsive-frame').responsiveIframe({
    xdomain: '*'
  });
});
```

I've tried using various shims like so:

```
  shim: {
    responsiveIframe: {
      init: function() {
        return this.responsiveIframe
      }
    }
  }
  ,
  shim: {
    'responsiveIframe': ['jquery']
  }
  ,
  shim: {
    'responsiveIframe': {
      'deps': 'jquery',
      'exports': 'ResponsiveIframe'
      'init': function() {
        return this.responsiveIframe.noConflict()
    }
  }
```

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about requireJS. Any help would be greatly appreciated, please let me know if you need more information :)

*edit*

Also, wrapping my responsiveiframe.js lib in this:

```
define(['responsiveIframe', 'jquery'], function(ri, jQuery) {
```

Seems to work... but this seems 'hacky'.

*edit #2*

***I was able to get this to work by wrapping the responsiveIframe lib like this:***

```
define(['jquery'], function(jQuery) {

  //library code here

}
```

I was able to remove all shims:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4000/assets',
  paths: {
    jquery: 'jquery-1.11.1.min',
    responsiveIframe: 'jquery.responsiveiframe'
  },
  map: {
    '*': {'jquery': 'jquery-lc'},
    'jquery-lc': {'jquery': 'jquery'}
  }
});
```

... and call like so:

```
require(['jquery','responsiveIframe'], function($) {
  $('#responsive-frame').responsiveIframe({xdomain: '*'});
});
```

*However, I am always a fan of doing things the 'right' way and modifying libraries rubs me the wrong way.*

***I feel like I should be able to use `shim` to properly apply this wrap code...***

Answer (score 1):

The last shim you tried was close, but the values of `deps` should be an array rather than a string. Try:

```
shim: {
    'responsiveIframe': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
```

This is ensure jquery is loaded *before* the responseIframe script is loaded and run.

Comment: This was one of the problems with my code, but I had more problems than this I guess :(

Answer (score 1):

You should set shim like this:

```
shim: {
    'responsiveIframe': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: '$'
    }
}
```

And change your module definition to this

```
define(['responsiveIframe'], function($) {
    $('#responsive-frame').responsiveIframe({xdomain: '*'});
}
```

That should do the trick

**UPD.**

If `exports` returns different jquery then you should modify shim to this:

```
shim: {
    'responsiveIframe': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        init: function(jquery) {
            return jquery;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, except I changed the `define` to `require`.

Comment: Actually, I thought this worked but it did not... `$` is referencing the wrong jQuery version (the one the initial page loaded, not requireJS). I will continue to investigate.